# Get text from dynamic dropdown and use it in another file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

On my web page I have two dropdown menus. One for a list of countries and another for a list of city's. The country menu is populated with data from a database. Once one of these countries are selected, the following dropdown is populated with corresponding cities via a php file (getdata.php) which takes the country value selected and queries it with a database and echos the city names into the dropdown. What I am struggling to work out is, when a city is selected, how would I get the text of the city selection and use this text in another php (displayCity.php) to query the database and echo values such as Population into the textbox (without reloading page) back on the web page? Would I need to make the displayCity.php similar to the getData.php? I have already created a new Ajax method for the textbox but I am not sure if I will need this. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php include_once "connection.php"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>City displayer</title>
    <h1>City displayer</h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepagestyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "country">
        <label>Select Country: </label> 
        <select name="country" onchange="getId(this.value);">
            <option value = "">Select Country</option>

            <?php
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(Country) from location AS Country FROM location ORDER BY Country ASC;";
                $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                foreach ($results as $country) {
                ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $country['Country']; ?>"><?php echo $country['Country'] ?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>   
    </div>  
</br>


</br>
    <div class="city">
        <label>Select a City: </label>
        <select name="city" id="cityList" onchange="showCity(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a city</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getId(value){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: "Country="+value,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#cityList").html(data);          
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</br>


    <div id = "textbox">Choose a country and city to display city name here</div>
        <script>
        function showCity(value){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "displayCity.php",
                data: "City="+value,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#textbox").html(data);           
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

getdata.php

```
<?php
include_once "connection.php";

if(!empty($_POST['Country'])){
    $country = $_POST['Country'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM location WHERE Country= '$country'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);


    foreach ($results as $city) {
    ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $city['Country']; ?>"><?php echo 
$city['City'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX along with a $_SESSION variable. No need to write it to the database. You just have to make sure you use session_start() everywhere you need it.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a session variable to the getdata.php file to get the $country = 'City' selected value. It is now displaying stuff in the text box, but not the value I want. Instead it shows the last value on the City dropdown menu instead of the one I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to use jquery to get the selected value.  $("#selectbox option:selected").text();

Comment: In which file? The main webpage, getData.php or do I need another php?

Comment: In the main  webpage. Use the selected value to pass on through AJAX.